# Why is my Constructor not working properly?

Tags: java, text, constructor

What I want is for my constructor to filter out what I have specified in a text file and then use my getLongestWord method based on the filtered text file.
I'm trying to make words containing 0-9 ignored, and any punctuation in a word is stripped before storage. Words that were purely punctuation are ignored. After the constructor returns, the new instance will have all the information it needs to do analysis; the file will not be needed again.

```
public class TextProcessorImpl implements TextProcessor {

private String filename;

public TextProcessorImpl(String filename) {
    this.filename = filename;
    String current;
    Scanner scan = TextReader.openFile(filename);
    ArrayList<String> lst = new ArrayList<String>();
    while (scan.hasNext()) {
        current = scan.next();
        if (current.matches(".*[0-9].*")) {

        }
        else {
            current = current.replaceAll("\\p{Punct}+", "");
            if (current.isEmpty()) {
            }
            else {
                lst.add(current);
            }
        }
    }
}

@Override
public Collection<String> getLongestWords() {


    String longestWord = "";
    String current;
    Scanner scan = TextReader.openFile(filename);   // Generate scanner
    ArrayList<String> lst = new ArrayList<String>();    //create array list
    while (scan.hasNext()) {    //while the text has a next word in it
        current = scan.next();  //set current to that next word
        if (current.length() > longestWord.length()) {  //if the current word length is greater than the longest word length
            longestWord = current;  //set the new longest word to current
            lst.clear();    //clear the previous array
            lst.add(longestWord);   //add the new longest word

        }
        else if( current.length() == longestWord.length()) { //else if the current word length = the longest word length
            if (!lst.contains(current)) {
                lst.add(current);   //add the current word to the array
            }
        }



    }return lst;

}
```

Main program:

```
public class TextAnalysis {

/**
 * Get a file name from the command line and ask a TextProcessor
 * to analyze it.
 *
 * @param args a single-element array containing the file name
 */
public static void main( String[] args ) {
    if ( args.length != 1 ) {
        System.err.println( "Usage: java TextProcessor file" );
        System.exit( 2 );
    }
    TextProcessor textProc = new TextProcessorImpl( args[ 0 ] );

    Collection< String > longestWords = textProc.getLongestWords();
    System.out.println( "Longest words: " + longestWords );

   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that the list you create is a local variable of the consructor :

```
ArrayList<String> lst = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Therefore, whatever data the constructor collects doesn't get stored in the instance.
You should make that `lst` a member of the class.

```
public class TextProcessorImpl implements TextProcessor {

private String filename;
private ArrayList<String> lst = new ArrayList<String>(); 

public TextProcessorImpl(String filename) {
    this.filename = filename;
    String current;
    Scanner scan = TextReader.openFile(filename);
    ...
```

Then your `getLongestWords` can use that list without having to read the file again (as it currently does).

Answer (score 0):

Your

```
ArrayList<String> lst = new ArrayList<String>();
```

is declare and initialized in the constructor. It is a local variable, Not a instance variable. Therefore you can't access it even though your logic works fine.
You can move the declaration part outside the constructore.

```
ArrayList<String> lst;
public TextProcessorImpl(String filename) {
     lst = new ArrayList<String>();
     ....
}
```